# Separate model factory file for every model

Tags: laravel

I'm using Factories in Laravel like that:

```
$factory->define(App\Federation::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $countries = Countries::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $users = User::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'president_id' => $faker->randomElement($users),
        'address' => $faker->address,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'country_id' => $faker->randomElement($countries),
    ];
});
```

The thing is, I have around 30 models, so this file is growing fast.

Is there a way to extract each Model Factory in own file, in the same folder? I think this is cleaner.

Comment: It looks like a fairly simple file, any reason you can't just create new files for each model and just require_once them from this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a factory specific to the `Federation` model, you can create a `FederationFactory.php` file in your `database/factories` folder.

From the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database-testing#model-factories):

All of the files within the `factories` directory will automatically be loaded by Laravel.